# How to use an background image for the section header in the UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

HI

I have a UITableViewController where I also use the section header.

Now is there any chance to use an image as background for the section header ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wanna look at this :

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

it returns the view that shows the header, here you can draw your background image as you wish.